# Flutter changing Text value using RiverPod State management

Tags: flutter, riverpod

In this below code i made simply code to change `Text` widget string, default string can be shown into `Text` widget but when i try to click `FloatingActionButton` is doesn't change.

clicking on `HotReload` cause chage it to new value, where i should change to resolve this issue?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/all.dart';


class MyString extends StateNotifier<String> {
  MyString() : super('Hello World');

  void change(String text) => state = text;
}

final showHello = StateNotifierProvider<MyString>((ref) => MyString());

void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('SAMPLE'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Consumer(
            builder: (context, watch, _) {
              final s = watch(showHello).state;
              return Text(s);
            },
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () => context.read(showHello).change('Clicked On Button'),
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**April 2021 Update**: As of Riverpod >= 0.14.0 the syntax has now been updated (scroll down for original answer). The following demonstrates how the example code provided in the question could be converted to the updated syntax:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Note importing hooks_riverpod/all.dart is now deprecated
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';


class MyString extends StateNotifier<String> {
  MyString() : super('Hello World');

  void change(String text) => state = text;
}

// Note the extra parameter, String, to specify what is provided by the Notifier
final showHello = StateNotifierProvider<MyString, String>((ref) => MyString());

void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('SAMPLE'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Consumer(
            builder: (context, watch, _) {
              // Note here, state does not need to be specified.
              final s = watch(showHello);
              return Text(s);
            },
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Note that we now specify notifier here to access non-state
            // attributes of the Notifier
            context.read(showHello.notifier).change('Clicked On Button');
          },
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

More on upgrading to Riverpod 0.14.0+ can be found [here](https://riverpod.dev/docs/migration/0.13.0_to_0.14.0).

---

The following contains the original answer to the question. It is only valid for **riverpod <= 0.13**.

Change:

```dart
final s = watch(showHello).state;
```

to:

```dart
final s = watch(showHello.state);
```

The reason for this behavior is that you are watching the notifier itself, not its state. Since the notifier object isn't actually being changed, just the state property, a rebuild is not triggered (which is why you see the update upon hot reload). By watching the state itself, we rebuild whenever the state changes.

This concept extends to other kinds of providers, e.g. [listening to the last exposed value of a StreamProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/all/StreamProvider/last.html).

[A similar question I answered in the past.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64146088/handle-authentication-with-riverpod/64146594#64146594)

Comment: You're welcome. I updated my answer with some explanation of why this behavior exists in case you are interested.

Comment: I have updated the example for the newest Riverpod 0.14.0+ syntax.

Comment: Could you add the difference between the state itself and the statecontroller(which we need to watch if we want to modifie the state itself)?

Comment: @SalahAdDin When using StateNotifier you don't update the state from outside of the StateNotifier class itself. Are you referencing StateProvider?

Comment: Yeah, StateProvider.

Comment: @SalahAdDin StateProvider isn't relevant to this question, if you'd like, open a separate question and I would be happy to answer.

Comment: Well, I got confused about this one... long story.