# Where should you place the state value in Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-state, riverpod

To access the state of a StateProvider or StateNotifierProvider:

Sometimes in the Riverpod documentation, the state variable is added after the watch function.

```
int count = watch(counterProvider).state;
```

However, my code where I am using a StateNotifier, works only if I refer to it inside watch. i.e

```
watch(myNotifier.state)
```

What are the differences?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter changing Text value using RiverPod State management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64341414/flutter-changing-text-value-using-riverpod-state-management)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The widget that is consuming the provider will behave differently in the two cases.

In the first case:

```
watch(counterProvider).state
```

The consumer will look at the entire counterProvider and it will be rebuilt if anything causes a NotifyProvider.

In second case:

```
watch(counterProvider.state)
```

The consumer is looking at the state variable only and it will only be rebuilt if the state changes and cause a NotifyProvider.

Comment: Thanks, please mark the question as correct if you think it is

Comment: Is 
watch(counterProvider.state)
the same as
watch(counterProvider) ?

Comment: Using watch(counterProvider.state) in flutter_riverpod: ^2.4.8 gets error:
'state' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Will be removed in 3.0.0. Use either `ref.watch(provider)` or `ref.read(provider.notifier)` instead.